# ios:Date picker with short format

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I want a date picker like this one, with the month name in **short format**:

[image]

But this is what I get:

[image]

> **This has the full month name, which is not what I want.**

I set date picker mode like this:

```
mydatepicker.datepickermode = datepickermode.date
```

but it's not working.

Comment: The code fragment you have provided will not compile. Please copy the code directly from your editor using the clipboard. Also, provide more context, such as the instantiations of the date picker object(s).

Answer (score 0):

Embedded datePicker is not very flexible to adjust. The way to solve your issue is to create your own picker by using `UIPickerView`. You need to create a picker with 3 components and configure it depending on your wishes. But this way is a little bit annoying, because you need to keep in mind, that every month has it's own number of days. And don't forget also about 29th of February.